# Is it possible to drag and drop a UWP StorageFile to desktop, created using CreateStreamedFileFromUriAsyc

Tags: winapi, drag-and-drop, uwp, storagefile

**The goal:**
What I want to do is drag a `GridViewItem` from a `GridView` in a UWP app *outside* of the app to the desktop explorer.  During the drop event, I want to download a file from the internet and create a `StorageFile` that will be used to populate the `DataPackage`.  I want this `StorageFile` to be copied to the desktop.  Unfortunately, when a deferral is used for UWP Drag&Drop (using `SetDataProvider`), as soon as you leave the app window, the request is activated and you have to populate the `DataPackage` with the object to be transferred.  So, it seemed to me that I would need to use a deferred type of `StorageFile` created with `CreateStreamedFileFromUriAsyc`.

*I do not want to pre-download the data every time I start to do a drag and drop operation.  I only want to download the data when I'm actually dropping it somewhere legitimate to copy.*

[image: App in action showing a file being dragged to the desktop.]

1. I know how to drag and drop a pre-existing `StorageFile` from UWP to Explorer (desktop) using a deferred request.
2. I also know how to create a `StorageFile` using `CreateStreamedFileFromUriAsyc` that will gives you a `StorageFile` that downloads data only when the data is requested.

When I try to combine these two ideas, windows Explorer gives me the error 'interface is not supported.'.

If I use the exact same code, but just get the file contents by calling something like GetBasicPropertiesAsync during the deferred drag handler, it works only if I hold the drag over the desktop until the file is downloaded. I can see it finishing when the drag icon changes from the 'prohibited' icon to 'copy'.  If I let go of the mouse button before it is done, no copy will occur and no errors are raised.

Obviously, I would like the drag and drop to download without having to manually start it on the deferred handler. Any ideas? Is this possible?

(Yes, I realize the code to create the correct file extension is wrong/incomplete, but that's irrelevant here...)

```
//DragStarted Handler in constructor
DragItemsStartedCommand = ReactiveCommand.Create<DragItemsStartingEventArgs>((e) =>
        {
            _dragItems = e.Items.Cast<ItemViewModel>();
            e.Data.Properties.Title = "Transfer file";
            e.Data.Properties.Description = "desscription of transfering a file";
            e.Data.Properties.FileTypes.Add(StandardDataFormats.StorageItems);
            e.Data.SetDataProvider(Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.StandardDataFormats.StorageItems, OnDeferredStorageFileRequestedHandler);
            e.Data.RequestedOperation = DataPackageOperation.Copy;
        });


 //Deferred request handler
    async void OnDeferredStorageFileRequestedHandler(DataProviderRequest request)
    {
        DataProviderDeferral deferral = request.GetDeferral();
        try
        {
            Task<IEnumerable<StorageFile>> task = null;
            await Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>
            {
                task = DownloadStorageFiles();
            });
            var result = await task;
            request.SetData(result);
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Handle the exception
        }

        finally
        {
            deferral.Complete();
            Debug.WriteLine("deferral complete!!!");
        }

    }

//Create StorageFile with deferred loading Task
    async Task<IEnumerable<StorageFile>> DownloadStorageFiles()
    {
        List<StorageFile> storageItems = new List<StorageFile>();
        foreach (var item in _dragItems)
        {
            var request = new RestSharp.RestRequest();
        var defaultItemType = ItemType.MSWord;
        switch (item.MimeTypeTranslated)
        {
            case ItemType.GoogleDocument:
            case ItemType.GoogleSpreadsheet:
            case ItemType.GooglePresentation:
            case ItemType.GoogleDrawing:
            case ItemType.GoogleScript:
                request.Resource = $"files/{item.File.id}/export";
                request.AddParameter("mimeType", Statics.ItemTypeDictionary.First(x => x.Value == defaultItemType).Key);
                break;
            default:
                request.Resource = $"files/{item.File.id}";
                request.AddParameter("alt", "media");
                break;
        }
        string fileName = "";
        if (item.File.name.EndsWith($".{Statics.ItemExtensionDictionary[defaultItemType]}"))
            fileName = $"{item.File.name}";
        else
            fileName = $"{item.File.name}.{Statics.ItemExtensionDictionary[defaultItemType]}";
        var uri = account.Client.GetAuthorizedUriForDownload(request);

        var thumbnail = RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromFile(await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///StoreLogo.png")));
        var storageFileDeferred = await StorageFile.CreateStreamedFileFromUriAsync(fileName, uri , thumbnail);
        //var props = await storageFileDeferred.GetBasicPropertiesAsync();                
         storageItems.Add(file);
        }
        return storageItems;
    }
```

GitHub repro of this problem:
https://github.com/limefrogyank/DragDeferredFileToDesktop

1. First page is a regular drag to desktop that works because StorageFile (+ underlying data) is already in assets folder
2. Second page shows the error generated when using a StorageFile that is created with CreateStreamedFileFromUriAsync.
3. Third page uses the same type of StorageFile, but with a hack to force the retrieval of data synchronously.  Desktop freezes for a second until data is ready.

Comment: I'm a little confused with your issues. Could you please detail that? For example, what're you trying to do? How and why you combine the two? Did you use a third party package? Did have have a [mcve] project?

Comment: I added a paragraph at the beginning that hopefully explains what I'm trying to do. I can try to create a minimal example project if that helps...

Comment: OK, it's clearly. For "I know how to drag and drop a pre-existing StorageFile from UWP to Explorer (desktop) using a deferred request." Could I know how you implement this? Did you use `ReativeUI`?

Comment: I have a reproduction on GitHub now .  Link is at the bottom of the question.  I'm getting mixed results using my "hack".  With the sample reproduction, it works except it locks up the desktop until the download is finished.  Still not a good result.

Comment: @LeeMcPherson Did you find any workaround? I also stumbled across this Ticket from Microsoft, seems they're working on it => https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsAppSDK/issues/140

Comment: No, I abandoned this project so I haven't tried lately.  Likely, you could switch to a desktop app and port most of the UWP code by using WinUI3.  Perhaps one could make this work that way...

Answer (score 0):

As of the recent Windows updates the drag n' drop of storage files on UWP apps is automatically handled by the system.

[example gif.](https://i.imgur.com/mSqGF4Y.gifv)

Comment: Even `StorageFile` created using `CreateStreamedFileFromUriAsyc`?  Because if the file is local, yes, `StorageFile` behaves normally... but if the `StorageFile` represents a stream of remote data, it didn't work when I posted this question originally...